# mvc use variable in layout page instead of its string value

Tags: javascript, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

This is probably a n00b question, I'm trying to get a string variable in my MVC _layout page

so far i have

EDIT:

```
@{
   string myVariable = @Html.Action("GetUserName", "UserController");
}
```

I need to show the `myVariable` multiple times on the page. Hence I need to store it somewhere rather than calling the
`@Url.Action("GetUserName", "UserController");`
multiple times.

Is there a way to do this in mvc?

EDIT 2:

I used 
`string myVariable = ViewBag.GetUserName()`
where

in my `BaseController()`, I have

```
public BaseController(){
  ViewBag.GetUserName = new Func<string>(GetUserName);
}

[AllowAnonymous]
public string GetUserName()
{
  return "Mark ZuckerBerg";
}
```

When i run my project I get,
`Cannot perform runtime binding on a null reference`

Comment: What url are you actually trying to generate? Do you want `"User/GetUserName/someUserName`? (And its `"User"`, not `"UserController"`). In any case, why assign it to a c# variable first? - it can just be `var testName = '@Url.Action(...)';`

Comment: im not trying to get the string value, i need the result of calling the URL. `var testName='Mark Zuckerberg'`

Comment: Then you need to call the controller method. `Url.Action()` is a method for generating a url (it does not actually call it). But why is the value of your UserName not available in the view? You need to provide some more context to understand what you really want to do.

Comment: all the controllers get called using javascript ajax calls, i just need to call it here using MVC as I want the value loaded before any of the javascript loads.

Comment: Then you need to make an ajax call to that controller method to get the value it returns.

Comment: does mvc provide a way to do ajax, i would wish to avoid jQuery as it needs to happen before javasript gets loaded

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `jquery` is `javascript` so why are you avoiding it? But why aren't you just passing the value to the view in the GET method?

Comment: i don't know how to create a get for layout page, i just have it for individual pages, is there any such tutorial, i'm not so good at mvc

Comment: Not really sure what your trying to do. If your wanting to display the current user name in the `_Layout.cshtml` then you could just add `<div>@ViewBag.UserName</div>` and in the GET method use `ViewBag.UserName = "...";`. Or you could add `@Html.Action("GetUserName", "User")` in the layout which will render the html returned by that method. Its not clear why you need to assign it to a javascript variable.

Comment: I did just what you described, but `ViewBag.UserName` is `null`. can you describe how to get this value? Also, with the `@Html.Action("GetUserName", "User")` -- can this be stored somewhere? i dont want to call it multiple times

Comment: You still have not explained what your wanting to do. There could be a hundred possible answers. You need to edit your question with some more details

Comment: To repeat, you still have not explained what your wanting to do. (and your edit suggests you maybe have other problems), but your edited code wont work - `@Html.Action()` generates content in the view, its not for assigning a value to a variable. Just use `@{ var myVariable  = ViewBag.UserName; }` and assign the value in the GET method - `ViewBag.UserName = "someValue";

Comment: @heyNow your question is still not very clear. What do you want to go into a string?  A URL or the Result of a URL.  If it is a URL or what the URL returns.  If it is a result you should get the variable in your controllers action. For example  `ViewBag.UserName = "J smith"`  then on you page you can access it via  `@ViewBag.UserName`.  Not need to Ajax or `@HTML.Action`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want is to call that action in YOUR controller action, and use the result. You can either pass the value as model to the view or pass via ViewBag.

```
public ActionResult MyAction()
{
    var userName = new UserController().GetUserName();

    return View(userName);
    //OR
    ViewBag.UserName = userName;
    return View();
}
```

Or, if you want to use in _Layout.cshtml create a child action, in UserController : BaseController

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public ActionResult UserName()
    {
        return new ContentResult { Content = "Mark ZuckerBerg" };
    }
```

and call in _Layout.cshtml

```
    @{Html.Action("UserName", "User")}
```

Comment: I tried this but `UserController` is null at that point, i think the _layout gets initialized first

Comment: Did you try this inside the controller action method or directly inside _Layout.cshtml file? I'm suggesting to do this inside your controller action and then passing on the value to the view.

Comment: doing `ViewBag.UserName = userName;` and refrencing `@ViewBag.UserName` in the layout page produces a blank result

Comment: Yes, Layout is called before before the action result. Have edited the answer with an alternative approach.

Comment: it works! finally! I tried you edited answer. Can't believe something so simple is made into so complicated in MVC

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using razor?

```
<input type="hidden" value="@myVariable" id='hidden-username'/>
```

Then access it on javascript/jQuery like this:

```
var hiddenUserName = $("#hidden-username").val();
```

Similarly, you can bind it to any other object that accepts the value of it:

```
<label id='lbl-username'>@myVariable</label>
<input type="text" value="@myVariable" />
```

Hope this helps.

How you get string myVariable depends upon you, but if you want it without any ajax calls, then you should bind it to the model of the page.

Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult YourPage()
        {
            YourPageModel pageModel = new YourPageModel();
            pageModel.UserName = GetUserName(userId);
            return View(pageModel);
        }
```

CSHTML(View):

```
@model  YourProject.YourPortal.Web.ViewModels.YourPageModel

 <label id='lbl-username'>@Model.UserName</label>
```

Comment: could you tell me how `@myVariable` would get its value (controller or any other way) ?

Comment: I would suggest binding the page to a model, and from here you can bind call the model to use the variable. I can show you an example if you want to.

Comment: is there a way other than model?

Comment: I think there are some ways but it's much messier, like loading everything via ajax call and appending it to the multiple times your username on load. 

The best way you could do this is via binding your view to the viewmodel.

In case you need some walk through on using model binding, I've added a simple example you could start on.